# ECS Fargate - No Space left on Device

Tags: aws-fargate

I had deployed my asp.net core application on AWS Fargate and all was working fine. I am using awslogs driver and logs were correctly sent to the cloudwatch. But after few days of correctly working, I am now seeing only one kind of log as shown below:

[image]

So no application logs are showing up due to no space. If I update the ECS service, logging starts working again, suggesting that the disk has been cleaned up.

This link suggests that awslogs driver does not take up space and sends log to cloudwatch instead.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_cannot_pull_image.html

Did anyone also faced this issue and knows how to resolve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you have logging configured in your application. The AWSlogs driver is just grabbing all the output sent to the console and saving it to CloudWatch, .NET doesn't necessarily know about this and is going to keep writing logs like it would have otherwise.

Likely .NET is still writing logs to whatever location it otherwise would be.

**Advice for how to troubleshoot and resolve:**

- First, run the application locally and check if log files are being saved anywhere
- Second, optinally run a container test to see if log files are being saved there too

  - Make sure you have docker installed on your machine
  - Download the container image from ECR which fargate is running.

    - docker pull {Image URI from ECR}
  - Run this locally

    - Do some task you know will genereate some logs
  - Use docker exec -it to connect up to your container
  - Check if log files are being written to the location you identified when you did the first test

Finally, once you have identified that logs are being written to files somewhere pick one of these options

1. Add some flag which can be optionally specified to disable logging to a file. Use this when running your application inside of the container.
2. Implement some logic to clean up log files periodically or once they reach a certain size. (Keep in mind ECS containers have up to 20GB local storage)
3. Disable all file logging(not a good option in my opinion)

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will follow your suggested steps and will get back with my observations.

Comment: I followed steps mentioned above and was able to find out the issue with disk space. In this case, culprit was one txt file in which errors were getting written over and over again and ended up with huge disk footprint. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @AMITSHARMA Where was the log location and how did you stop this?  I have a similiar issue, using log4net with <appender name="AWS" type="AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender,AWS.Logger.Log4net"> but the container is also out of space.  Id like to determine how to stop it writing to the container at all if possible

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur File name was aws-logger-errors.txt. It was created at the same location where my dll was running inside the container. Since my application was asp.net core, solution given by Paul T Davies below is exactly what I used to solve the issue i.e in appsettings file, use "LibraryLogFileName": null

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the "LibraryLogFileName" parameter in your AWS Logging configuration to null.

So in the appsettings.json file of a .Net Core application, it would look like this:

```
"AWS.Logging": {
  "Region": "eu-west-1",
  "LogGroup": "my-log-group",
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  },
  "LibraryLogFileName": null
}
```

Comment: Along the same lines as the above, if you are using NLog and setting up an `AWSTarget` in code, there is a property with the same name which should also be set to null to avoid this problem eg

```
AWSTarget awsTarget = new AWSTarget()
{
    LogGroup = serviceConfig.LogGroup,
    Region = serviceConfig.Region,
    LibraryLogFileName = null,
};
```